# iText does not work when adding many fields

Tags: java, groovy, pdf-reader, acrofields, pdfstamper

i have problem in generating PDF with iTextPDF (no errors in console but no pdf in output).

```
 AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields()
        form.setGenerateAppearances(true)
        form.setField("code", "value")
        others fields.....
      
        stamper.setFormFlattening(true)
        stamper.setFreeTextFlattening(true)
```

when i remove some fields it works but when i put all the fields that i want to display in PDF it doesn't work and i have no error.
Please is there a max of fields that we can add in AcroFields, if yes can we change it?

Comment: How many fields are you adding?  Is there a cutoff point you've found by trial and error?

Comment: i added 54 fields and unfortunately i have no errors no message of exception